# async method callback with Task.ContinueWIth?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I have a method that pulls some HTML via the HttpClient like so:

```
public static HttpClient web = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<string> GetHTMLDataAsync(string url)
{                    
    string responseBodyAsText = "";
    try
    {
       HttpResponseMessage response = await web.GetAsync(url);
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       responseBodyAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // Error handling
    }

    return responseBodyAsText;
}
```

I have another method that looks like so:

```
private void HtmlReadComplete(string data)
{
    // do something with the data
}
```

I would like to be able to call GetHTMLDataAsync and then have it call HtmlReadComplete on the UI thread when the html has been read.  I naively thought this could somehow be done with something that looks like

```
GetHTMLDataAsync(url).ContinueWith(HtmlReadComplete);
```

But, I can't get the syntax correct, nor am I even sure that's the appropriate way to handle it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public async void ProcessHTMLData(string url)
{
    string HTMLData = await GetHTMLDataAsync(url);
    HTMLReadComplete(HTMLData);
}
```

or even

```
public async void ProcessHTMLData(string url)
{
    HTMLReadComplete(await GetHTMLDataAsync(url));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but `ContinueWith()` takes a delegate with `Task` as its parameter, so you can do:

```
GetHTMLDataAsync(url).ContinueWith(t => HtmlReadComplete(t.Result));
```

Normally, you should be careful with using `Result` together with `async`, because `Result` blocks if the `Task` hasn't finished yet. But in this case, you know for sure that the `Task` is complete, you `Result` won't block.